# Differentiability of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to study differentiability of $f$ at the origin:

$$ f(x,y) = ( x^3 + y^3)^{1/3} $$

MY attempt: I claim $f$ is not differentiable at the origin because its partial derivatives are not defined at the origin. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. It seems to me that the derivatives exist but are not continuous in the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If differentiable, then all the directional derivatives exist and
$$
D_{(u,v)}f(0,0)=(Df(0,0))(u,v).
$$
In this case, all the directional derivatives exist:
$$
D_{(u,v)}f(0,0)=(u^3+v^3)^{1\over3}
$$
but $(u^3+v^3)^{1\over3}$ isn't a linear funtion of $(u,v)$.

Answer (score 2):

The two partials exist and are each $1$. For example to find $f_x$ at $(0,0)$ we insert the $0$ for $y$ and get simply $f(x,0)=x$, whose ordinary derivative is $1$. Then according to [this reference](http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/2934/cal148.pdf) (and any good calc 2 book), $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ iff the relative error $E=(x^3+y^3)^{1/3}-x-y$ is such that
$$H(x,y)=\frac{E}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \to 0,$$
as $(x,y) \to (0,0).$ However if we take $t>0$ we find that $H(t,t)$ is the constant $(2^{1/3}-2)/\sqrt{2},$ and so the approach to $(0,0)$ along $y=x$ from quadrant I does not give the required limit of $0$ for $H(x,y).$